# How would you translate this ? Y uncido que fue su carro

Tags: traducción, gramática

Esto es muy extraño para una principiante como yo.

Espanol de la Biblia:
"Y uncido que fue su carro"

...and yoked that was his chariot?

Answer (score 1):

Según RAE

> Uncir: 1. tr. Atar o sujetar al yugo bueyes, mulas u otras bestias.

Por lo que se interpreta:

> Entonces Joram dijo: 'Unce'. Y uncido que fue su carro, Joram rey de Israel, y Ocozías rey de Judá, cada uno en su carro, salieron a encontrar a Jehú. Y lo hallaron en la heredad de Nabot de Jezreel.

- Entonces Yoram dijo: '¡Enganchen los caballos!' Y los engancharon a su carro. Yoram, rey de Israel y Ocozías, rey de Judá, fueron a encontrar a Jehú cada uno en su carro; y se toparon con él en el campo de Nabot de Yizreel.

<sub>*Fuente [www.bibliatodo.com](https://www.bibliatodo.com/biblia/reina-valera-1990-adventista/2reyes-9-21)*</sub>